# Using JACK in virtual machine?

Tags: sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, virtualization, jack

Is it possible to run JACK audio software in Ubuntu in a Virtualbox virtual machine?

If it is, what software configurations would need to be done? Add user to audio group? Threadirqs added into kernel?

jackd qjackctl pulseaudio-module-jack  packages installed?

Would CPU frequencies need to be changed to Performance rather than Ondemand? Is that possible in a virtual machine?

Comment: It is certainly possible to run it in a VM. The audio infrastructure is still going to be ALSA inside the VM guest. However, I highly doubt you're going to get anywhere near the latency requirements for pro audio, while running the stuff in a VM. The setup of jack itself would roughly be the same as doing it on bare metal.

Comment: Are there any Virtualbox settings that need to be set for JACK to work? What would cause it to have lots of xruns when in the virtual machine?

Comment: You have lots of xruns in the VM, because you're in a VM.

Comment: That is, you might be able to lower the latency if you were to do full PCI passthrough of the USB or Firewire host device, to the VM, but there will still likely be latency issues due to the virtualized CPU, RAM, and disk access.

Comment: I tried, but it never worked for me. However, for virtualization, there might some alternative tech possible, if someone develop it, like x11docker.